# Average value of last 1000 simulation steps algorithm in C-code

Tags: algorithm

I want to use C to calculate the average value of last 1000 simulation steps inside software I am using.
Step size of solver is 1 ms, and one of the signals is oscillating, thus I want to filter that signal to be more smooth. Our software enables us to use c-code as interface, that means I am driving the signal (the one that oscillates) into the C code as a[0] variable and what I receive from the c-code is y[0], which represents filtered signal. Information between c-code and software are exchanged each time step.

Now I want to know how this code should look like. The idea for the code is to calculate each time step averaged value of last n steps, where n value determines how many history time steps I want to consider. I would start with n=1000 and then decrease/increase this value depending on situation.

Comment: If by floating you mean that a[0] is changing each time step then answer is yes. So a[0] is value that comes from my software (from some lookup table) and by each time step a[0] is different value. C code should somehow store last 1000 points and then delete last one each time step, so that average value is always done for last 1000 points. This is only an idea how it could be, of-course any other solutions are more then welcome=).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Exponential Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) filter.

For practical application, you can use following code:

```
static double ema_val = 0.0;        // Initial value
static double ema_k   = 1.0 / 1000; // Weight of single event in sum

// Code for update the average value ema_val with the new_val
ema_val += ema_k * (new_val - ema_val);
```

Comment: Beat me to it :). Of course this is the preferred solution because it does not need to memorize any array of values.

Comment: The "'memory" of the process can be adjusted by tuning ema_k. The lower ema_k the higher the memory (system moves slowly). ema_k = 1 => no memory (no filtering).

Comment: It is more efficient and a good solution, but not what was asked: the average of the last n values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I have been looking for and it is sufficient enough for my usage. I am sorry I do not have enough reputation points to give you "vote up".

Comment: @AlesCvikl But you should be able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities.

Here some pseudo code, there is a startup phase until we have 1000 values and then the position always has the index of the oldest value which is replaced by the new one:

```
init: max = 1000, total = 0, count = 0,  values[max], position = 0

step(value) {
   total += value;
   if (count == max)
      total -= values[position];
   else
      count++;
   values[position++] = value;
   if (position == max)
      position = 0;
   return total / count;
}
```

Comment: If you are using floating point numbers (e.g. double) the total might slowly deviate from the real value and it is safer to recalculate it after some time.

Comment: Thanks also for your effort!